# Failed install 12.04 on Intel Hardware Raid with Large Partition (> 2TB)

Tags: installation, hardware, raid

I have Intel Hardware Raid on the motherboard.

I have 10 2 TB HDD that I've configured as RAID 1+0 to be one big 8 TB HDD.

Now I'm trying to install ubuntu 12.04 on it.

After installing with default desktop installation disk I get a blank screen with a cursor flashing.

If I try the alternate guided partitioning option I get error: out of disk. and the grub> prompt.

If I boot with the rescue disk or such like I can drop into a shell and view the disk. Everything also installs without an issue.

Don't know what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the alternate text-based installer which you can find here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

You may need to give yourself a separate /boot partition near the beginning of the hard drive array when you are choosing the partitioning. Your BIOS may have a limit on how large of a disk it can initialize the boot from.

Comment: Tried that combination, now I get Unknown filesystem when grub tries to boot

Comment: What was is your partition scheme (sizes, filesystem, location)? An example scheme might be:

`| boot ext4 10 GB | root ext4 7.98 TB | swap 10 GB |`

(just as an example)

Comment: thanks for the help, turns out a guided install from the alternate installer worked fine.